# Why is vagrant not mounting /vagrant?

Tags: linux, vagrant

I'm trying the simplest of vagrant configurations, but it is not mounting /vagrant as I would expect.  The permissions of the local dir seem reasonable, and I don't se anything in the debug output that would give me a clue why.

```
$ ls -ld .; ls -la .; cat Vagrantfile; VAGRANT_INFO=debug HOME="$(pwd)" VAGRANT_HOME="$(pwd)" VAGRANT_CWD="$(pwd)" vagrant up
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx 25 Jul 30 14:44 .
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx 25 Jul 30 14:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 xxx xxx 80 Jul 30 14:23 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 78 Jul 30 14:44 Vagrantfile
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu2004"
end
==> vagrant: A new version of Vagrant is available: 2.2.9 (installed version: 2.2.8)!
==> vagrant: To upgrade visit: https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'generic/ubuntu2004' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'generic/ubuntu2004'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/generic/ubuntu2004
==> default: Adding box 'generic/ubuntu2004' (v3.0.18) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/generic/boxes/ubuntu2004/versions/3.0.18/providers/virtualbox.box
    default: Calculating and comparing box checksum...
==> default: Successfully added box 'generic/ubuntu2004' (v3.0.18) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'generic/ubuntu2004'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'generic/ubuntu2004' version '3.0.18' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant4_default_1596121068354_68108
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: 
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default: 
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
$ vagrant ssh

vagrant@ubuntu2004:~$ ls /vagrant
ls: cannot access '/vagrant': No such file or directory
vagrant@ubuntu2004:~$
```

I have tried adding an explicit synced_folder as described [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder = "/local/xxx/vagrant4/", "/vagrant"
  config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu2004"
end
```

But that causes an error:

```
vm:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: synced_folder
```

This is with vagrant 2.2.8:

```
$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 2.2.8
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `synced_folder` should be used like a function call, not an assignment. I don't see an easy way to tell which to use in the documentation, aside from examples, but this should work:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder "/local/xxx/vagrant4/", "/vagrant"
  config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu2004"
end
```